# How to pull likes(that have a link) from users wall using Graph API

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, graph

I am new to graph api. I need to pull all the likes( that has a link) from users wall. Please let me know how to do this using graph api.I am using

https://graph.facebook.com/fb_id/feed?access_token=......&limit=.....&since=unix_time

but this doesn't return likes. Its only returning shared links.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the /me/likes connection? It requires an access token. Try it out here:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/